# Sending an invoice returns: "Incoming JSON request does not map to API request"

Tags: api, rest, paypal

I'm trying to send an invoice to a customer, however I receive:

```
[name] => MALFORMED_REQUEST
[message] => Incoming JSON request does not map to API request
[information_link] => https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#MALFORMED_REQUEST
```

I am sending the following:
Note I am json encoding, and I have also tried with & without the commented part. 
My my header application type is json.
Submission URL: https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment

```
$f = array(
        /*"intent" => "sale",
        "redirect_urls" => array(
            "return_url" => "http://www.return.com/",
            "cancel_url" => "http://www.cancel.com/"
        ),
        "payer" => array(
            "payment_method" => "paypal"
        ),
         *
         */
        "requestEnvelope" => array(
            "errorLanguage" => "en_US"
        ),
        "invoice" => array(
            "merchantEmail" => "merchant@domain.com",
            "payerEmail" => "payer@domain.com",
            "currencyCode" => "USD",
            "paymentTerms" => "DueOnReceipt",
            "merchantInfo" => array(
                "address" => array(
                    "line1" => "Address"
                )
            ),
            "itemList" => array(
                "item" => array(
                    array(
                        "name" => "Item1",
                        "quantity" => "25",
                        "unitPrice" => "3"
                    ), array(
                        "name" => "Item2",
                        "quantity" => "32",
                        "unitPrice" => "3"
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

`"invoice" => array(
            "merchantEmail" => "merchant@domain.com",
            "payerEmail" => "payer@domain.com",
            "currencyCode" => "USD",
            "paymentTerms" => "DueOnReceipt",
            "merchantInfo" => array(
                "address" => array(
                    "line1" => "Address"
                )
            )`

You should read how a `invoice-object` is declared https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#invoice-object

E.g. `invoice-object`s don't have the keys `merchantEmail` , `payerEmail` .....
your array is totally wrong